# Enabling soft-keys navigation bar with custom ROM on Xolo A500S

Tags: custom-roms, softkey

I have Xolo A500S. I want to have navigation bars (soft-keys), but it does not work manually or by any app. Here is the `build.prop`.

```
# begin build properties
# autogenerated by buildinfo.sh
ro.build.id=JDQ39
ro.build.display.id=Dark PureLolli By ACRD 
ro.build.version.incremental=eng.root.1376978569
ro.custom.build.version=Dark Purelolli by ACRD TeaM
ro.build.version.sdk=17
ro.build.version.codename=REL
ro.build.version.release=5.0
ro.build.date=Sat Feb 22 22:51:08 WIB 2014
ro.build.date.utc=1376978866
ro.build.type=user
ro.build.user=root
ro.build.host=software
ro.build.tags=release-keys
ro.product.model=Y511
ro.product.brand=HUAWEI
ro.product.name=Y511
ro.product.device=HUAWEI
ro.product.board=Y511
ro.product.cpu.abi=armeabi-v7a
ro.product.cpu.abi2=armeabi
ro.product.manufacturer=Nexus
ro.product.locale.language=es
ro.product.locale.region=ES
ro.wifi.channels=
ro.board.platform=
# ro.build.product is obsolete; use ro.product.device
ro.build.product=Nexus
# Do not try to parse ro.build.description or .fingerprint
ro.build.description=a101-user 4.4.2 JDQ39 eng.yiqinpan2.1384491559 test-keys
ro.build.fingerprint=alps/a101/a101:4.4.2/JDQ39/1384491559:user/test-keys
ro.build.flavor=
ro.build.characteristics=default
# end build properties

# begin mediatek build properties
ro.mediatek.version.release=ALPS.JB3.MP.V1.2
ro.mediatek.platform=MT6572
ro.mediatek.chip_ver=S01
ro.mediatek.version.branch=ALPS.JB3.MP
ro.mediatek.version.sdk=1
# end mediatek build properties
#
# system.prop for generic sdk
#

rild.libpath=/system/lib/mtk-ril.so
rild.libargs=-d /dev/ttyC0


# MTK, Infinity, 20090720 {
wifi.interface=wlan0
# MTK, Infinity, 20090720 }

# MTK, mtk03034, 20101210 {
ro.mediatek.wlan.wsc=1
# MTK, mtk03034 20101210}
# MTK, mtk03034, 20110318 {
ro.mediatek.wlan.p2p=1
# MTK, mtk03034 20110318}

# MTK, mtk03034, 20101213 {
mediatek.wlan.ctia=0
# MTK, mtk03034 20101213}


#
wifi.tethering.interface=ap0
#

ro.opengles.version=131072

wifi.direct.interface=p2p0
dalvik.vm.heapgrowthlimit=128m
dalvik.vm.heapsize=256m

# USB MTP WHQL
ro.sys.usb.mtp.whql.enable=0

# Power off opt in IPO
sys.ipo.pwrdncap=2

ro.sys.usb.storage.type=mtp,mass_storage

# USB BICR function
ro.sys.usb.bicr=yes

# USB Charge only function
ro.sys.usb.charging.only=yes

# audio
ro.camera.sound.forced=0
ro.audio.silent=0

ro.zygote.preload.enable=0

# temporary enables NAV bar (soft keys)
# amoi:disable NAV bar
qemu.hw.mainkeys=1

ro.kernel.zio=38,108,105,16

# TimeZone China ,chenxc,2012-05-22
persist.sys.timezone=Europe/Moscow

# Boot,Shutdown ring on/off, luohw, 2013-01-21
persist.sys.ring_on_or_off=1

#
# ADDITIONAL_BUILD_PROPERTIES
#
persist.gemini.sim_num=2
ro.gemini.smart_sim_switch=false
ro.gemini.smart_3g_switch=1
ril.specific.sm_cause=0
bgw.current3gband=0
ril.external.md=0
ro.sf.hwrotation=0
ril.current.share_modem=2
curlockscreen=1
ro.mediatek.gemini_support=true
ro.operator.optr=OP02
ro.operator.spec=SPEC0200
ro.operator.seg=SEGA
persist.radio.fd.counter=15
persist.radio.fd.off.counter=5
persist.radio.fd.r8.counter=15
persist.radio.fd.off.r8.counter=5
persist.mtk.wcn.combo.chipid=-1
drm.service.enabled=true
fmradio.driver.enable=1
ril.first.md=1
ril.flightmode.poweroffMD=1
ril.telephony.mode=3
dalvik.vm.mtk-stack-trace-file=/data/anr/mtk_traces.txt
mediatek.wlan.chip=mediatek.wlan.module.postfix=_
ril.radiooff.poweroffMD=0
ro.config.ringtone=Themos.ogg
ro.config.notification_sound=Tejat.ogg
ro.config.alarm_alert=Oxygen.ogg
ro.setupwizard.mode=ENABLED
net.bt.name=Android
dalvik.vm.stack-trace-file=/data/anr/traces.txt

#Init.d for boot.img
sys.initd=1
sys.initd.loop=1

#Quality pictures 100%
ro.media.enc.jpeg.quality=100
camera/camcorder mods
ro.media.capture.maxres=8m
ro.media.capture.fast.fps=4
ro.media.capture.slow.fps=120
ro.media.capture.flash=led 
ro.media.capture.flashMinV=3300000
ro.media.capture.torchIntensity=40
ro.media.capture.flashIntensity=70
ro.media.panorama.defres=3264x1840
ro.media.panorama.frameres=1280x720
ro.camcorder.videoModes=true
ro.HOME_APP_ADJ=1
debug.sf.hw=1
ro.media.dec.jpeg.memcap=8000000
ro.media.enc.hprof.vid.bps=8000000
ro.ril.hsxpa=2  
ro.ril.gprsclass=10
ro.ril.hep=1
ro.ril.enable.dtm=0
ro.ril.hsdpa.category=8 (or 10,12,14) Still looking for more of these though.
ro.ril.enable.a53=1
ro.ril.enable.3g.prefix=1
ro.ril.htcmaskw1.bitmask=4294967295
ro.ril.htcmaskw1=14449
ro.ril.hsupa.category=6

net.tcp.buffersize.default=4096,87380,256960,4096,16384,256960
net.tcp.buffersize.wifi=4096,87380,256960,4096,16384,256960
net.tcp.buffersize.umts=4096,87380,256960,4096,16384,256960
net.tcp.buffersize.gprs=4096,87380,256960,4096,16384,256960
net.tcp.buffersize.edge=4096,87380,256960,4096,16384,256960
# More free ram and apps load faster
dalvik.vm.dexopt-flags=m=y

#Responsiveness scroll
windowsmgr.max_events_per_sec=150

#Improving the quality of the microphone
ro.ril.enable.amr.wideband=1
ro.sf.lcd_density=200
#tweaks
ro.lolly.rom.name=Lolly Rom
ro.lolly.rom.version=v1.00

# Mejora el rendimiento de la bateria 
ro.ril.disable.power.collapse=1 
pm.sleep_mode=1 
wifi.supplicant_scan_interval=180 

#Mejora Bateria
echo "500" > /proc/sys/vm/dirty_expire_centisecs 
echo "1000" > /proc/sys/vm/dirty_writeback_centisecs
```

Please help.

Comment: If you have root, you can use Xposed framework and install one of the modules for soft-keys. BTW, build.prop doesn't have anything to do with having soft-key buttons.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this line to the end to fix it

qemu.hw.mainkeys=0

It should enable it. I wouldn't understand why you would want soft keys, but there you go.

I would recommend you to use build prop editor in the play store. It backs up your build.prop before you do anything.